# Change UI URL of Argo CD

Tags: azure-aks, azure-application-gateway, argocd, traefik-ingress

### Setup

I am using an Azure Kubernetes Cluster with Azure Application Gateway.
The external domain is `aks-tst.myurl.com`. The Application Gateway overrides this host to `aks-tst.intern.com` and forwards the requests with a self signed certificate to the AKS which has the following ingress for most of the applications defined:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
spec:
  rules:
    - host: aks-tst.intern.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: {{ .Values.ingress.path }}
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: {{ .Values.service.name }}
                port:
                  number: {{ .Values.service.port }}
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - aks-tst.intern.com
```

Argo CD values.yaml:

```
server:
  insecure: true
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - aks-tst.intern.com
    paths:
      - /argocd
    tls:
      - hosts:
          - aks-tst.intern.com
```

The generated Ingress for Argo CD:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argo-cd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-server
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v2.8.4
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: argo-cd
    helm.sh/chart: argo-cd-5.46.7
  name: argo-cd-argocd-server
  namespace: argocd
spec:
  ingressClassName: traefik
  rules:
  - host: aks-tst.intern.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: argo-cd-argocd-server
            port:
              number: 80
        path: /argocd
        pathType: Prefix
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - aks-tst.intern.com
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: <ip-of-traefik-loadbalancer>
```

### Problem

The ingress works fine for any application we define. But the Argo CD UI is not available. If accessing `aks-tst.myurl.com/argocd` the browser receives the response 307 and gets directly redirected to `aks-tst.intern.com/argocd` which is obviously not available from outside of Azure.

Is there a way to tell the Argo CD UI to use the external URL for redirects?

### What I've tried so far

#### Configmap `argocd-cm`

Argo CD values.yaml:

```
configs:
  cm:
    # tried with and without protocol and with and without path /argocd
    url: https://aks-tst.myurl.com
```

The value above generates the following configmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: server
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: argo-cd
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: argocd-cm
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: argocd
    app.kubernetes.io/version: v2.8.4
    argocd.argoproj.io/instance: argo-cd
    helm.sh/chart: argo-cd-5.46.7
  name: argocd-cm
  namespace: argocd
data:
  admin.enabled: "true"
  application.instanceLabelKey: argocd.argoproj.io/instance
  exec.enabled: "false"
  server.rbac.log.enforce.enable: "false"
  timeout.hard.reconciliation: 0s
  timeout.reconciliation: 180s
  url: https://aks-tst.myurl.com
```

This didn't work either so I added the following part to the argocd-server deployment manually and restarted all the pods in the `argocd` namespace:

```
...
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      ...
      - args:
        ...
        volumeMounts:
        ...
        - mountPath: /etc/argo-cd/config/cm
          name: argocd-cm
      volumes:
      ...
      - configMap:
          defaultMode: 420
          name: argocd-cm
        name: argocd-cm
```

The pod then shows these logs:

```
url modified. restarting
shutting down settings watch
Shut down requested
0xc000f810e0 unsubscribed from settings updates
rbac configmap informer cancelled
argocd v2.8.4+c279299 serving on port 8080 (url: https://aks-tst.myurl.com/argocd, tls: true, namespace: argocd, sso: false)"
Enabled application namespace patterns: argocd
0xc000bd9500 subscribed to settings updates
Starting rbac config informer
RBAC ConfigMap 'argocd-rbac-cm' added
```

Comment: Create a config map called argocd-cm with the following key-value pair: url: https://aks-tst.myurl.com/argocd
Mount the config map into the Argo CD server pod. You can do this by editing the Argo CD server deployment and adding the following volume and volume mount:
volumes:
  - name: argocd-cm
    configMap:
      name: argocd-cm
volumeMounts:
  - name: argocd-cm
    mountPath: /etc/argo-cd/config/cm

Restart the Argo CD server pod.

Comment: @Arko Thanks for the quick reply. But it did not work. See edited question for details

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution after reading [this](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-cd/issues/2953) and [this](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/operator-manual/ingress/) article for the 10th time.

There were two main mistakes in my config:

1. The `insecure` property does not belong to the `server` config within the values.yaml, but to the `configs` part.
2. The ConfigMap URL does not set the path, it is being set in a separate property.

The correct `values.yaml` looks like the following. No manual configuration except the `values.yaml` was needed:

```
configs:
  params:
    server.insecure: true
    server.rootpath: /argocd
  cm:
    url: https://aks-tst.myurl.com

server:
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    hosts:
      - aks-tst.intern.com
    paths:
      - /argocd
    tls:
      - hosts:
          - aks-tst.intern.com
```